# Why the Scala fascination with flatmap? (This doesn't seem to be the same for mapcat in the Clojure world)

Tags: scala, clojure, community

In the Scala community - there is [an apparent fascination with the FlatMap function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559537/where-does-the-flatmap-that-s-idiomatic-expression-in-scala-come-from).

Now I understand that FlatMap is significant because it is used for the bind part of a Monad. (and that the Clojure community hasn't dived into Monads yet, with [some](http://www.intensivesystems.net/tutorials/monads_101.html) [wonderful](https://thestrangeloop.com/sessions/monads-made-easy) [exceptions](http://www.leonardoborges.com/writings/2012/11/30/monads-in-small-bites-part-i-functors/)).

Now in the Clojure Community - there is no corresponding cultural idiom, eg "MapCat that S***".

My theory on the difference between the two communities and the reason for this difference is that the concurrency primitives in Clojure lend it towards solving problems on a single machine, in a single instance. (Ie Clojure is good at concurrency). Whereas in the Scala World, with the rise of the Actor model, Scala is a little more focused on solving multi-machine problems. This focus on multi-machine problems has a higher focus on breaking problems down into their parts, and a greater focus on what can be broken down and Scale. (eg Monoids) (Now I realise there is an STM in Scala, and that Actor models, Avout and Cascalog are wonderful exceptions to this - I'm making a generalization)

My question is, why the [Scala fascination with flatmap](http://web.archive.org/web/20130627111326/http://beust.com/weblog/2010/07/28/why-scalas-option-and-haskells-maybe-types-wont-save-you-from-null/comment-page-1/#comment-8222)?

(I'm not trying to start a flamewar - I think both communities have benefited from each others existence - I'm trying to understand a cultural behaviour).

Comment: If you don't want to start a flamewar (or battle of downvotes/closevotes), you might want to clean up your question. Try to make it clearer what you are actually asking, and try to remove any incendiary language. E.g., `“*why the Scala emphasis*” is better than “*why the Scala obsession*”.

Comment: Done - if you can suggest any others that would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now I understand that FlatMap is significant because it is used for the bind part of a Monad. (and that the Clojure community hasn't dived into Monads yet, with some wonderful exceptions).

I think that's pretty much the entire explanation. Many Scala idioms and approaches are derived from Haskell, and so it pays a lot of attention to type-safety, monads, etc.

> Now in the Clojure Community - there is no corresponding cultural idiom, eg "MapCat that S***".

`mapcat` only works with collections, unlike `flatMap`.

> This focus on multi-machine problems has a higher focus on breaking problems down into their parts, and a greater focus on what can be broken down and Scale. (eg Monoids) (Now I realise there is an STM in Scala, and that Actor models, Avout and Cascalog are wonderful exceptions to this - I'm making a generalisation)

Better example of this in Clojure core is Reducers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "mapcat only works with collections, unlike flatMap"?

Comment: What's to elaborate? `mapcat` is specifically for collections. It isn't part of a protocol, so can't be made to work on other types. In Scala any monad-like type can define a `flatMap` method.

Comment: You're implying that mapcat is inferior to flatmap - and I'd like some details on why they're different.

Comment: No, I am implying mapcat is a specific particular case of flatMap.

Comment: Ok - could you provide a link to explain that further?

Comment: Ok - answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363205/what-are-the-differences-between-mapcat-in-clojure-and-flatmap-in-scala-in-terms/20404879?noredirect=1#20404879